# Get image name of impaths in python

Tags: python, title

I have a impaths function in my document that gives the whole path of images back, e.g.:
/../Documents/Furniture/1.jpg
/../Documents/Furniture/2.jpg
… up to 40 images.

If i print the impath I always get the whole path back. Is there a way I can only get the image names back (e.g. 1.jpg, 2.jpg).

```
for i in range (len(impaths)):
    impath = impath[i]
    print impaths
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `os.path` module. If you want to parse the path, you can use the `split` method

```
import os

s = "your/path/image.jpg"
print (os.path.split(s)[-1])
```

If you just want the filename you can use `basename`

```
print(os.path.basename(s))
```

There are a lot of useful path-related methods in the module that I would suggest using over manually parsing your paths.